# How to set automatic time for Quiet hours in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, automation, cortana

I wanted to set automatic rules for Quiet hours features in Windows 10. I want quiet hours to automatically activate during specific time.

In Windows 10 Mobile I have done the same by going to Cortana->Notebook->Quiet Hours. However I cannot do the same on Windows 10 PC. There is no quiet hour page in Cortana's notebook on PC.

Is the setting located somewhere else or is it not implemented yet? Any solution such as registry edits is also welcome.

---

Note: I know how to set Quiet hours manually in Action center(by pressing WIN + A). And I'm not asking that. Procedures that involve manual work each time is not what I need. I am looking for setting quiet hours through an automated process(like in Windows phone).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are asking to set the time during which quiet hours should remain enabled automatically then please follow these steps

- **For Windows 10 Home Users**

open the Registry Editor by hitting Start and typing “regedit.” Press Enter to open Registry Editor and give it permission to make changes to your PC. In the Registry Editor, use the left sidebar to navigate to the following key:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion

Next, create a new subkey inside the CurrentVersion key.

Right-click the CurrentVersion key and choose New > Key. Name the new key QuietHours.

[image: Quiet Hours]

Now, you’re going to create two new values inside the new QuietHours key. Right-click the QuietHours key and choose New > DWORD (32-bit) Value. Name the new value EntryTime.

[image: As here]

Create a second DWORD value in the QuietHours key and name it ExitTime.

The EntryTime value specifies the time that Quiet Hours begins and the ExitTime value the time that Quiet Hours ends. Open each value in turn by double-clicking it. In the properties window for each value, set the “Base” option to “Decimal.” In the “Value Data” box, you’ll type the number of minutes after midnight that you want to trigger the event. So, for example, you might set the EntryTime value to 120 for 2:00am (120 minutes after midnight) and the ExitTime Value to 600 for 10:00am.

[image: as here]

You can now close Registry Editor. The changes take place immediately, so there’s no need to restart your PC or anything. The new Quiet Hours start and end times should be in effect from now on. To reverse the change, just follow the same steps and delete the QuietHours key you made, which will also delete the two values you created in that key.

- **Pro and Enterprise Users: Change Quiet Hours with the Local Group Policy Editor**

If you’re using Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise, the easiest way to change Quiet Hours is by using the Local Group Policy Editor. It’s a pretty powerful tool, so if you’ve never used it before, it’s worth taking some time to learn what it can do. Also, if you’re on a company network, do everyone a favor and check with your admin first. If your work computer is part of a domain, it’s also likely that it’s part of a domain group policy that will supersede the local group policy, anyway.

In Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise, hit Start, type gpedit.msc, and press Enter.

In the Local Group Policy Editor, in the left-hand pane, drill down to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Notifications. On the right, you’ll be working with two settings: “Set the time Quiet Hours begins each day” and “Set the time Quiet Hours ends each day.”

[image: Image here]

Double-click the “Set the time Quiet Hours begins each day” setting to open its properties window. In the window, click the “Enabled” option and then use the “Minutes after midnight” box to set the number of minutes after midnight that Quiet Hours begins. In this example, we’re going for 120 minutes, which would be 2:00am. When you’re done, click “OK.”

[image: as here]

Now, you’ll use the same procedure with the “Set the time Quiet Hours ends each day” setting to configure the number of minutes after midnight that Quiet Hours ends. So, for example, we might set 600 minutes so that Quiet Hours ends at 10:00am.

After configuring both settings, you can exit Local Group Policy Editor. Changes are immediate, so no need to restart Windows. And if you want to turn off your new settings at any time, just go back in to Local Group Policy Editor and change both those settings to “Not Configured.” Windows will then return to using the default 12:00am–6:00am Quiet Hours.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work. Maybe there is some additional option?

Comment: There should also be an `Enable` DWORD set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can set quiet hours in windows 10

## Method 1

Step 1 - PC Settings

Step 2 - Search And Apps Settings

Step 3 - Notifications and you will be able to set custom hours there.

## Method 2

Step 1 - Windows Key + A(To open windows action center)

Step 2 - You can switch on Quiet hours there.

Comment: There is no Search and Apps settings in PC. There is only Cortana & Search and Notifications and Actions. Both dose not contain any setting you mentioned. Can you post a screenshot. And the method 2 is completly unnecessary. My question How to set automatic time and not how to do it manually. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: @KolappanNathan. After some research and me idiotically being unaware that i am using insider preview, I found out that customization of quiet hours is not available for windows 10 yet. I am sorry for the inconvenience caused by my idiocy. Since its inside the insider preview, it is very likely for it to happen in the next update

Comment: Can u provide me the build number you are running? So that I can check on my PC once it is released to public.

Comment: i am using Build 14905, August 17 update:>

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll watch out for the update. You could add your comments(atleast the build number) in your answer. Anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: Guys, can you kindly explain me how Quiet Hours should work? I set up new hours [through GPO](https://www.howtogeek.com/279192/how-to-change-the-default-quiet-hours-in-windows-10/), but QH mode is not switched off after my custom hours. Is it a bug or it doesn't work like this?